# How to prevent table from resizing in Tailwind css?

Tags: html, vue.js, html-table, tailwind-css

So, i have this table

```
< table class="table-fixed border-separate border border-green-800">
          < thead class="bg-indigo-800 border-b-2 border-indigo-200 w-full">
            < tr>
              < th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white min-w-10 max-w-10"
                v-if="isEditable"
              >
                  Select
     
              </th>
              < th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white min-w-20 max-w-20"
                @click="setSort('username')"
              >
                
                  Username
              </th>
              < th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white min-w-30 max-w-30"
                @click="setSort('firstName')"
              >
               
                  Name
               
              </th>
              < th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white min-w-30 max-w-30"
                @click="setSort('lastName')"
              >
                  Surname
              </th>
              < th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white min-w-40 max-w-40"
                @click="setSort('email')"
              >
                  Email
               
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          < tbody class="divide-y divide-grey-100">
            < tr
              v-for="student in studentsToshow"
              :key="student.id"
              :class="[
                isStudentSelected(student.id)
                  ? 'bg-blue-500 ring ring-blue-300'
                  : '',
              ]"
            >
              < td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 w-10"
                v-if="isEditable"
              >
                < input
                  type="checkbox"
                  v-model="selectedStudents"
                  :id="student.id"
                  :value="student"
                  class="form-checkbox rounded text-indigo-600 mr-2 focus:ring-indigo-600"
                />
              </td>
              < td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
                {{ student.username }}
              </td>
              < td`enter code here`
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
                {{ student.firstName }}
              </td>
              < td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
                {{ student.lastName }}
              </td>
              < td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
                {{ student.email }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

The problem i have is that when the student's field change their size, all the table just follow the resizing while i want it to stay fixed. The most ugly scenario is when the student array is empty and the table suddenly downsize (because columns are empty). Is there a way to fix the table size? I've tried fixing max and min height in header, but no success

Answer (score 1):

Give a fixed width to all theads (except the first one) using `w-52` and remove all the `min-w-20` and `max-w-20`.

Below is the implementation

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<section>
  <table class="table-fixed border-separate border border-green-800">
          <thead class="bg-indigo-800 border-b-2 border-indigo-200 w-full">
            <tr>
              <th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white w-30"
                v-if="isEditable"
              >
                  Select
     
              </th>
              <th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white w-52"
                @click="setSort('username')"
              >
               
                  Username
              </th>
              <th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white w-52"
                @click="setSort('firstName')"
              >
               
                  Name
               
              </th>
              <th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white w-52"
                @click="setSort('lastName')"
              >
                  Surname
              </th>
              <th
                class="px-4 py-2 text-white w-52"
                @click="setSort('email')"
              >
                  Email
               
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="divide-y divide-grey-100 text-center">
            <tr
              v-for="student in studentsToshow"
              :key="student.id"
              :class="[
                isStudentSelected(student.id)
                  ? 'bg-blue-500 ring ring-blue-300'
                  : '',
              ]"
            >
              <td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 w-10"
                v-if="isEditable"
              >
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  v-model="selectedStudents"
                  :id="student.id"
                  :value="student"
                  class="form-checkbox rounded text-indigo-600 mr-2 focus:ring-indigo-600"
                />
              </td>
              <td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
              {{ student.userName }}  
              </td>
              <td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
              {{ student.firstName }}  
              </td>
             
              <td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
                {{ student.lastName }}
              </td>
              <td
                class="border border-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-black font-medium"
              >
                {{ student.email }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</section>
```

Make sure to open the above implementation in full page. You can check by editing the value in the table cell also .